# @RequestMapping on Class, set Value from @Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web

I have a endpoint using @RequestMapping(), but currently it just contains a hardcoded String as the path. Is there someway to do that in a configureable way. Currently we use a @Configuration which sources different propertySources.

Example of endpoint(as it is now)

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("endpoint-path")
public class Endpoint {....}
```

Example how Config class is

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("....")
@ConfigurationProperties
@Validated
public class EndpointConfiguration {...}
```

Just mentioning that I dont just want to reference the propertyfile, I want to reference the property class. **Not as below**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("${endpoint.path}")
public class Endpoint {....}
```

**EDIT:** So As the comment mention lets see an example how I could want it "somewhat" like, as I don't suppose it succeed as that.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(EndpointConfiguration.getEndpoint().getPath())
public class Endpoint {....}
```

any other ways to define the request mapping of a class with a @Configuration, as it was said annotation would have to know at compile time.

Comment: dont understand what you want to do? Can you show it?

Comment: @mark-rotteveel How is this the same question. It seems you have not at all read it. I CLEARLY defined that I was not looking for a propertyFile lookup.

Comment: Well, you can't. Hardcoded strings or strings with Spring expression language are the only way. That is a limitation of annotations in Java (the value must be known at compilet time).

Comment: @mark-rotteveel. In that case that is an answer to my question, but redirecting it as a duplication is clearly **incorrect**

Comment: I disagree, the answer to that question quotes the documentation, which makes clear that what you want is not possible. If you disagree with that assessment, I suggest that you make an edit to your question so it triggers a reopen review and will see what other reviewers think.

Comment: @markRotteveel you could argue that. but in that case the duplicate part is only the answer rather than the question. quoting above statement of "marked duplicate" is **This question was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question**